# Dart feed template/generic class with Type object, is it possible?

Tags: flutter, class, dart, generics, types

Is it possible to some how achieve something like that?

```dart
class SomeClass<T> {

}
```

And then use or feed it as following?

```dart
Type someType = MyType;

SomeClass c = SomeClass<someType>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
class SomeClass<T> {
}
typedef DataList = List<int>;
SomeClass c = SomeClass<DataList>();
```

Note that before Dart 2.13, aliases (typedef) were allowed for functions only. Static analysis will ask you to to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.14.0 or higher before allowing you to compile. You can do that in you pubspec.yaml

Comment: Thats a nice feature but it doesn't really solve my Problem. What I want to achieve is to store some types in variables and based on certain settings the app dynamically use different templates

Comment: I answered your initial question. I suggest you open another question where you explain what you want to achieve. It will be easier to help with your problem.

Comment: @iOSonntag That's not possible.  You're asking to do something at runtime that must be resolved at compilation-time.